# Find the partial derivative for given functions

Tags: calculus

Given  $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is a differentiabel function I have to find the partial derivative for the following functions:

a. $(x,y) \mapsto f(2x,3y)$ b. $(x,y) \mapsto f(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))$ but I just get confused. Normally I would have function defined, for an example, as
$$
f(x,y) = x^2+y^2
$$ where it is easy for me to understand how to find the partial derivative in terms of either x or y. What do I do in this case with these functions? Is it simply that
$$
\frac{\partial f(2x,3y)}{\partial x} = f(2)
$$
? Or how do I interpret the functions given? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can think of it as the composition of two functions $(x,y) \mapsto (2x,3y)$ and $(u,v) \mapsto f(u,v)$. Its partial derivatives can be represented by partial derivatives of $f$ by $x$ and $y$, of $2x$ by $x$ and $y$, and of $3y$ by $x$ and $y$ , by the chain rule of partial derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the chain rule:

For part a)

$$\frac{\partial f(2x,3y)}{\partial x}=(2+0)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2x,3y)=2\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2x,3y)$$

$$\frac{\partial f(2x,3y)}{\partial y}=(0+3)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(2x,3y)=3\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(2x,3y)$$

For part b)

$$\frac{\partial f(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))}{\partial x}=(2x+\cos(x))\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))$$

$$\frac{\partial f(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))}{\partial y}=(2y+0)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))=2y\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2,\sin(x))$$